# How to implement SSL/HTTPS for Tomcat/GeoServer on AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu)?

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

I installed GeoServer 2.18 on my AWS EX2 instance, by Tomcat. Now how do I implement SSL certificate/https  on Tomcat, so the WMS/WFS reuqests become secure? or change some setting in GeoServer?

Comment: GeoServer doesn't care, this is just about how you configure Tomcat, if Tomcat is indeed your public web server interface, or (more commonly) your web server such as Apache HTTPD /NGINX.  Obviously you'll need some SSL certificate for your domain

Answer (score 2):

If Tomcat is the public interface to GeoServer then one way is to edit the `server.xml` file with details of your SSL certificate like:

```
<Connector
    maxThreads="150"
    minSpareThreads="25"
    port="8443"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    server="Not-Important"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    defaultSSLHostConfigName="*.some.domain.uk"
    xpoweredBy="false"
    maxParameterCount="1000">
    <SSLHostConfig
         certificateVerification="none"
         hostName="*.some.domain.uk"
         sslProtocol="TLS"
         protocols="TLSv1.2">
         <Certificate
             certificateKeyPassword="blahblahblah"
             certificateKeystoreFile="/path/to/tomcat/variant/latest.pfx"
             certificateKeystorePassword="blahblahblah"
             certificateKeystoreProvider="SunJSSE"
             certificateKeystoreType="PKCS12" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
 </Connector>
```